# Unique constraint on tables for particular values of a field

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, unique-key

I have an invoice table. It has many fields, but the problem is around 2 main fields

- InvoiceNo - alphanumeric values
- Deleted - boolean 1 or 0 ,to represent a record is deleted or not.

Our business requires InvoiceNo to be unique. However if a row is deleted we can re-use the InvoiceNo

```
InvoiceNo    Deleted
123Er        1
123Er        0
```

Above is a valid use case. But i don't want to have another record with 123Er & 0.

Is it possible to create unique key on combination of 2 fields for certain values Unique (InvoiceNo, Deleted=0) or should we go for stored procedure or triggers ?

Comment: What is the issue with just updating the `Deleted` column to indicate whether or not a unique record is available?  I don't see what your problem is actually.

Comment: Just using a unique `InvoiceNo` (without a possibility of re-using it ) is likely to save you _lot_ of headache.

Comment: @DenisKniazhev as a business case, we need to support deleting a record and re-use the `InvoiceNo` again

Comment: In my opinion, deleting invoice, creating again with same invoice number and deleting again will fail on duplicate row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rename the field something like `DeletedIfNull` (or `IsActive`).

Then, the field would take the value of "1" or "true" or whatever if the column is active.  It would be `NULL` for any other values.  Then you can create:

```
create unique index unq_t_invoiceno_isactive on t(invoiceno, isactive);
```

MySQL (although not all databases) allows repeats when a unique index is defined.  Hence, this will solve your immediate problem.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite easy to achieve in other RDBMS systems with help of a [function based index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_index)

As for now MySql doesn't have such a feature, but starting from version 5.7 it can be simulated with use of a virtual (or generated) column.

Simple working example: http://rextester.com/HGY68688

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable1234(
  InvoiceNo varchar(10),
  Deleted int,
  xxx varchar(10) generated always as (case when deleted = 0 then InvoiceNo end) virtual
);

create unique index myindex12 on mytable1234( xxx );

INSERT INTO mytable1234( InvoiceNo, Deleted)  VALUES ('aaa1', 0 );
INSERT INTO mytable1234( InvoiceNo, Deleted)  VALUES ('aaa1', 1 );
INSERT INTO mytable1234( InvoiceNo, Deleted)  VALUES ('aaa1', 1 );

-- INSERT INTO mytable1234( InvoiceNo, Deleted)  VALUES ('aaa1', 0 );
```

If you uncomment the last INSERT in this snippet, and then try to run this snippet, then you will get: `Duplicate entry 'aaa1' for key 'myindex12'` error.
In this way, there may be multiple records in the table with the same `InvoiceNo` value for `deleted = 1`, but only one value for `deleted = 0`, because MySql will not allow this.

Comment: @krokodilko . . . Actually, many other databases support filtered indexes, which is a much more direct solution.

Comment: Clever -- but requires that `NULLs` be treated as unequal to each other.

Answer (score -1):

You can just create a unique key (InvoiceNo, Deleted), and its done. I dont understand why you need to make (InvoiceNo, Deleted=0), which is not supported. Having a unique key of those 2 columns provide you what you need.

UPDATE: 
I got your problem that you might have 2 deleted rows of same values. In this case, i would suggest you prepend *something* to InvoiceNo column of deleted values so that they won't be unique.

For example:
You have *123er* and then delete it, so it becomes *123er-1*. When you delete another one, it becomes *123er-2*. You can even do it basically in an update(before) trigger.

Comment: We need to maintain history, so modifying existing data is a violation. Also if the choice is to use triggers, i can validate my values `before insert` instead of updating existing records.

Comment: Then instead of unique constraint, you can define a standard index on those columns, and you can query the table on that index to see if there is a duplicate record before doing your insert. This way you programmatically solve the problem, and it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Programmaticaly this solves, but i wish to establish constraint at database level. Thanks

Comment: Or set `deleted` to the next higher value, not always `1`.